# Why webdriver unix executables are converted to textedit files on maven build?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have imported browser webdriver for different operating systems into my eclipse maven project. In project folder they are identified as unix executables (working on mac), but when I execute `mvn package` in target folder I see them as textedit files.

[image]

What can be the issue there?

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution, if you don't want to store webdrivers in your project.
I used webdriver-manager for this, you can import it in your pom.xl file

```
<dependency>
<groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
<artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
<version>3.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```